# redirection error loop?? | multiple .html on url

Tags: html, adobe, redirect, muse

On 2 of our websites:

realestateconcierge.co.uk (getstarted subdomain works fine) & stonelinkinternational.com

If you navigate through the pages, they don't load up - we're receiving a redirection error and the URL has so many .html on it.

This is so bizarre for us as we've never ever come across this issue before. We've not even touched the files on the server - it's been months, and the website was working fine - we've realised today this problem exists.

An example of one page:

http://realestateconcierge.co.uk/me-personal-relocation.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html

Please can someone shine a light on this - much appreciated!

Kind Regards, Sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Change or edit `.htaccess` file.